# Removing low frequencies from a signal

Tags: matlab, lowpass-filter, adaptive-filters

I am trying to remove low frequencies from a signal and intuitively I chose the high-pass filter, more specifically - a Butterworth filter, Order 4 (because I am not sure how to choose properly the order and 4 seemed as a good choice) and cutoff frequency of 50 Hz. The problem is, that the filter removes the low frequencies, however, the peaks that were caused from those low frequencies are still to be seen.

I have read also about adaptive filtering, but according to the literature, I need a reference signal, which would be used as a desired signal. I tried implementing an adaptive RLS/LMS filter and as a reference signal, I processed my data with a low-pass filter - Butterworth, 4th Order, 50 Hz for the cutoff frequency. This method also did not get me far.

I have provided a [a copy of my data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k5i3gavyczor2y1/AAAhtWISRs0wHgIT66xVP3gAa?dl=0), which is sampled at 1500 Hz.
[image]

Comment: Could you tell what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Royi I am trying to remove the peaks in the signals (that is the hearth beat, which should be below 30-40 Hz). That is why I have used 50 Hz as cutoff frequency.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "remove low frequencies" for your signal? Are you trying to remove the "blips" that seem to appear roughly every 1 second in this signal?

Comment: @AtulIngle That is exactly my goal. I am sorry, if I have made it unclear.

Comment: Your fundamental mistake is that eventhough those heartbeat peaks have a period which approximately gives a fundamental frequency of 35 Hz, the **quasi periodic** beat pattern do have many *harmonics* in higher frequencies as a matter of continuous Fouerier series analysis. You should either try a **comb** filter, or use a nonlinear and/or time varying filter (an example is an adaptive filter) to remove those peaks without degrading the original signal.

Comment: Rather than talking about removing unwanted signal, of you look at the spectrum of your unfiltered signal, can you point out where your signal of interest lies?

Comment: Or even more important: what *is* your signal of interest? This might be a case of http://xyproblem.info

Comment: **correction** the heartbeat signal is of course something about 1-2 Hz for a normal being :-) , I don't why he's interested in 30-40 Hz range but nevertheless the heartbeat signal is not periodic and it has a lot of harmonic and inharmonic components above its fundamental and probably above 50Hz as well...

Comment: It's all heart beat. What do you want to preserve, P wave? ST segment?  There are a number of fairly standard QRS detectors, you could just detect and blank the QRS complex.

Comment: I am interested in investigating the error, so that is why I want to remove the hearth beat from the signal. After looking at the frequency domain, I decided to use a highpass filter with a cutoff frequency of 50 Hz, as the majority of the signal, which I want to remove is in that area.

Comment: "I am interested in … the error" That requires you to define the *error between which and what*! So, what error are you talking about?

Comment: again, you're only describing what you want to remove, not what you want to have. This is definitely getting a bit tiring.

Comment: I am sorry if I have made it unclear. As said, I want to remove the hearth beat and analyse the other part of the signal. Using the highpass filter, as mentioned in some papers, did not do the trick for me and after reading the comments, I tried removing the harmonics in the higher frequencies, using a notch filter. This did not get me far as well, as I could not remove all of them. My end goal is to filter out the hearth beat and preserve as much as possible from the higher frequencies, while the QRS is completely filtered out.

Comment: To confirm: You are trying to remove the PQRST blips, and analyze the "noise" that is left over after removing the heart beat signal? Note that this is the opposite of what most signal processors would want to do - usually we are interested in obtaining a clean heart beat signal and removing the noise.  I am asking this because the broader picture of what you are trying to do will help us help you better.

Comment: @AtulIngle that is exactly what I am trying to achieve. The hearth beat (and the harmonics, which come because of it) is of least interest to me, so my goal is to remove it in order to evaluate the other part of the signal.

Comment: @Fat32 I filtered the harmonics with a notch filter, however, using a highpass filter afterwards does not end up removing the hearth beats.

Comment: @Fat32 I changed it to Matlab version 5 or later and uploaded it, so there are 2 files now.

Comment: I have forgotten to change the link. My bad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64514/discussion-between-filtfilt-and-fat32).

Comment: @filtfilt I've to leave now, please update your question with as much detail as yo can provide. In the mean time please search the site for related topics including *ECG signals* and *Adaptive Noise Cancellation*..

Comment: @filtfilt please edit the text in your question in light of all the clarifications and comments in this long comments section. Please also update the title of your question accordingly.

Comment: @AtulIngle I will edit my post with the new information. I saw your answer and the algorithm looks good, however, I was thinking, would it be possible to use a smoothing filter - median filter, Savitzky–Golay smoothing filter or any other filter to get the hearth beat (or at least something resembling it) and remove it with an adaptive filter from the original signal?

Comment: @filtfilt I don't know. You'll have to try that yourself. You should edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I will try it, but when using an approximation of the heart beat attained by a smoothing filter, wouldn't I end subtracting more than the heart beat?

Answer (score 5):

You want to remove the heart beat signal and keep the "noise". We can solve this problem by using a denoising algorithm, and subtracting the denoised signal from the original signal.

Setting frequency cutoffs for a frequency domain filter can get tricky and turn into a game of whack-a-mole because there's "high frequency" components in the heartbeat blip (due to the sudden rise and fall) and also in the wiggly stuff between a heart beat's T wave and the next heart beat's P wave.

Loosely speaking, the requirements in this de-noising problem are as follows:

- Remove the little wiggles
- Maintain larger jumps that appear in a heart beat PQRST waveform

This sounds like a great place to apply $\ell_1$ denoising or total variation denoising. The idea is to approximate the given signal $y$ with a signal $x$ such that the derivative of $x$ is "sparse" i.e. it doesn't change too frequently, but when it changes, the change is large. The denoised estimate $\hat x$ is given by:
$$
\hat x = \min_x ||y-x||_2^2 +\lambda\sum|x_i-x_{i-1}|
$$

I used [proxTV toolbox in Python](https://github.com/albarji/proxTV) to solve this optimization problem.

```
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import prox_tv as ptv

mat_struct = sio.loadmat('Signal1.mat')
noisy_signal = mat_struct['x'].T[0]

filtered_signal = ptv.tv1_1d(noisy_signal, 50)

time_vec = np.linspace(0, len(noisy_signal)/1500., len(noisy_signal))

plt.close('all')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1,sharex=True)

ax[0].plot(time_vec,noisy_signal)
ax[0].set_title('noisy signal')

ax[1].plot(time_vec,filtered_signal)
ax[1].set_title('filtered signal')

ax[2].plot(time_vec,noisy_signal - filtered_signal)
ax[2].set_title('noise')
ax[2].set_xlabel('time (s)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show(block=False)
```

And here's the resulting plot:
[image]

Of course, there's a different kind of whack-a-mole you'll have to play with this technique: the $\lambda$ parameter which I set to $50$ in the code.

Comment: Thanks! I will test it on my computer as well! However, I would like to ask what is the cause for the peaks on the places, where the QRS was?

Comment: The algorithm isn't perfect after all! You'll notice, by playing with the $\lambda$ parameter, you can get those peaks to go away, at the price of adding some extra wiggles in the filtered signal. Also note that the y axis labels on the bottom subplot are different, about 1/10th of those of the top two.